# 1. How to detect a keystoke? 2.How to skip a comand line?

Tags: javascript

I have iMacros on FireFox. This is a .js file that I can't get it to work.

It gives me this error `SyntaxError: syntax error, line NaN (Error code: -991)`

All my other .js files work just fine.

If someone can help me I would appreciate it a lot.

Once its working, I need-it to listen to a specific keystroke "numpad 0" wich is Code 96 and run macro07. Then, if marcro02 - macro05 is not playable/clickable because the button is not their, then skip the rest of the macros and play macro06.

In advance, I would like to say: Thank-you very much...

```
for( i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){

    var macro;

    var i, retcode, errtext;

    var macro01;

    var macro02;

    var macro03;

    var macro04;

    var macro05;

    var macro06;

    var macro07;

    macro = "VERSION BUILD=8510617 RECORDER=FX" + " \n ";

    macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + " \n ";

    macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 15" + " \n ";

    macro += "TAB T=1" + " \n ";

    macro += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + " \n ";

    macro += "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#game_content>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>A:nth-of-type(1)" BUTTON=0" + " \n ";

    macro += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + " \n ";

    macro01 += "CODE:";

    macro01 += "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#game_content>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>A:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0" + " \n ";

    macro01 += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + " \n ";

    macro02 += "CODE:";

    macro02 += "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#game_content>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>A:nth-of-type(3)" BUTTON=0" + " \n ";

    macro02 += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + " \n ";

    macro03 += "CODE:";

    macro03 += "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#game_content>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>A:nth-of-type(4)" BUTTON=0" + " \n ";

    macro03 += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + " \n ";

    macro04 += "CODE:";

    macro04 += "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#game_content>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>A:nth-of-type(5)" BUTTON=0" + " \n ";

    macro04 += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + " \n ";

    macro05 += "CODE:";

    macro05 += "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#game_content>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>A:nth-of-type(6)" BUTTON=0" + " \n ";

    macro05 += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + " \n ";

    macro06 += "CODE:";

    macro06 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next" + " \n ";

    macro06 += "WAIT SECONDS=0.5" + " \n ";

    retcode = iimPlay(macro)

    macro07 += "CODE:";

    macro07 += "WAIT SECONDS=20" + " \n ";

    macro07 += "BACK" + " \n ";

    macro07 += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + " \n ";

    macro07 += "BACK" + " \n ";

    macro07 += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + " \n ";

    macro07 += "BACK" + " \n ";

    macro07 += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + " \n ";

    retcode = iimPlay(macro)


}
```

Comment: I would formulate the questions in the body rather than the title.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of this.

```
macro05 += "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#game_content>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>A:nth-of-type(6)" BUTTON=0" + " \n ";
```

Use this,

```
macro05 += 'EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#game_content>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>A:nth-of-type(6)" BUTTON=0" + " \n ';
```